# can we increase or decrease India map using google map api?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using jquery google map api (from fidler). But in my code proper kashmir and some other states are not visible. Please suggest how can I display the full India map along with all Unitary Territory.

Comment: change the pixel values in the style attribute to increase width & height of the map . And if you wan to  zoom out map then use 'zoom' key.

Answer (score 1):

You can make adjustments on the view of your map so that you can view the rest of the states. Just make the value of zoom smaller.

You can refer to this code:

```
    var maparea = {lat: 12.8797, lng: 121.7740};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: maparea
```